Importing Temporary Excel Files into R
I am trying to import some files from excel (xlsx) to R. However, some of these files have a ~$ in the title. E.g. folder_name/~$file_i_want.xlsx.
Reading online, I see that a ~$ might indicate that the file is a temporary file or an incomplete file.
Normally, I import files into R using some either the data.table::fread(), read.csv or readxl::read_excel() functions. However, none of these functions appear to be working.
Is it some how possible to force R to import these files?
Thanks

Show the full code and error messages.

readxl::read_excel("~$data.xlsx") works for me. Note that fread and read.csv are for importing TEXT files, not Excel files.
